# how to show a screen if sony smartwatch is locked

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

How to show a screen in sony smartwatch 2 when screen is locked like we does with a call application. even if the screen is locked when we receive a call it shows upfront. I am able to show this when my app is open through a control api. but when my app is not open and some event happen in my mobile app i have to show the same in smart watch as well. I think we can do this with tunnel service but i dont know how. Pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start a ControlExtension on SmartWatch2, there is a `startRequest` command, which can be sent this way:

```
protected void startRequest() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Control.Intents.CONTROL_START_REQUEST_INTENT);
    sendToHostApp(intent);
}
```

where

```
protected void sendToHostApp(final Intent intent) {
    ExtensionUtils.sendToHostApp(mContext, mHostAppPackageName, intent);
}
```

- `mContext` is the Context of your activity or service, from where you are sending the command
- `mHostAppPackageName` is the name of the invoked device host application, in this case for SmartWatch2: `"com.sonymobile.smartconnect.smartwatch2"`

This command will start and show the `ControlExtension`, which is registered in your application.